# Testing removing items from a React controlled list with Cypress

Tags: reactjs, typescript, testing, cypress, cypress-each

I created a React list from which users can delete items by clicking a button.

Deletion is handled like this:

```
 const handleRemove = (index: number) => {
   onChange(fieldName, (prevState) => {
     return {
       ...prevState,
       [fieldName]: prevState[fieldName].filter((_: any, i: number) => i !== index),
     };
   });
 };
```

When I test it manually it works fine, but when I test it with Cypress deleting items doesn't work as expected, some items remain. *(I assume)* the problem is that Cypress presses each 'list deletion button' at the same time, and deleting items by index can't be trusted when the list changes rapidly. In real life this can't cause any problems, right?

If it can, how should I rewrite the deletion logic?

If it isn't a big deal though, how can I rewrite my Cypress test to wait a few milliseconds while React does its thing with state updates?

This is what I came up with after a few hours of tinkering:

```
cy.get(".fa-solid.fa-minus").each((element, index) => {
      cy.wait(index * 3).then(() => {
        element.trigger("click");
      });
});
```

Comment: This looks like a useful question that other people could learn from, but in its current form it is difficult to understand it. What is the essence of what you are asking and could you provide a working code as a basis for the answer, perhaps modifying that from the accepted answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `each()` loop is **processing too fast** to allow the app to complete each delete action.

The inner loop needs an **assertion to confirm the action has completed**. Cypress waits for that assertion before performing the next iteration.

In the example below the assertion checks to see that the list length has decreased.

In absence of a complete example I used the following component:

```js
import React from 'react';
import {useState} from 'react'

const initialList = ['Cypress', 'Javascript', 'Typescript']

export const List = () => {
  const [list, setList] = useState(initialList)

  const handleRemove = (index) => {
    setList(prevState => prevState.filter((_, i) => i !== index))
  }

  return (
    <ul>
      {list.map(function(item, index) {
        return <>
          <li key={item}>{item}</li>
          <button onClick={() => handleRemove(index)}>Delete</button>
        </>
      })}
    </ul>
  )
}
```

This is the test

```js
const itemList = ['Cypress', 'Javascript', 'Typescript']

const selector = 'button:contains("Delete this one")'

cy.get(selector)
  .each(($el, index, $list) => {
    cy.get(selector).first().click()

    // wait for action to complete

    // using list count
    cy.get(selector).should('have.length', $list.length - index -1)

    // or using item text
    cy.contains(itemList[index]).should('not.exist') 
  })

cy.get(selector).should('not.exist')       // all gone
```

This is the log for the passing test

[image]

Comment: Hey! Thank you for your answer. I tried your solution and I got "Message:  expected [ <i.fa-solid.fa-minus>, 7 more... ] to have a length of 7 but got 8". Do you have any guesses how may I resolve this?

Comment: I tested with a simple React component, details posted above. The only thing I had to change was `'.eq(index)` to `.first()` because the indexes change on each iteration.