# Cypress - terminate function if condition fails

Tags: cypress

[image: This is our app's UI.]

In the screenshot above, there are 4 products. Each unpicked product will have a `Pick` button. To the right of the `Pick` button is the quantity. If the user clicks the `Pick` button, the product will be listed under `PICKED ITEMS`. If the user clicks the `Pick` button for `Product #1` 3x, it will be removed from the `UNPICKED ITEMS` list, and will be moved to the `PICKED ITEMS` list.

Now I want to write a Cypress e2e test that will click the `Pick` buttons `X` times, where `X` is the total quantity of all the products under `UNPICKED ITEMS`. In the screenshot below, the total should be 10, because the other 2 are already picked.

[[image: 2]Here's what I've tried](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jm5rG.png)

[[image: 3]But it continues to run even after all buttons have been clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dFxUq.png)

Comment: Hi Freddy, welcome on StackOverflow. Could you please insert your code as text (formatted as code block) in the question, instead of the screenshot? Also, I don't understand what your actual question is.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Technically the function keeps calling itself because you are not waiting for the `click()` events to process.

But there are other problems, for example `res` ***will never equal 0***.

If that condition *were* true, the preceding query `cy.contains('Unpicked items')...` would not find any elements and the test would fail.

Instead use `.each()` to click every button.

There not enough detail to give you a proper answer, but this is a rough approximation based on this answer
[Testing removing items from a React controlled list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77466891/testing-removing-items-from-a-react-controlled-list-with-cypress)

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('unpickedItems', () => {
  cy.contains('Unpicked items')
    .parent().find('Pick')
    .filter(':visible')
})

cy.unpickedItems().then(intialItems => {

  let initialCount = intialItems.length

  cy.unpickedItems()
    .each((item,index) => {

      // remove an item
      cy.unpickedItems().first().click()

      // verify there is one less item
      cy.unpickedItems().should('have.length', intialCount - index -1)
    })
})

cy.unpickedItems().should('not.exist')
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Unfortunately, I'm getting this error:

contains
Pick
        22
        assertexpected <button.button.btn-pick-manual> to have a length of NaN but got 1
        23
        shouldhave.length, NaN

CypressError
You must provide a valid number to a length assertion. You passed: NaN

Comment: I have solved the problem. Although this answer didn't directly solve my question, the key was "res will never equal to 0". That was a clue that I had to revise my approach.

Comment: Hi Freddy, thanks for your feedback. If you like you can post your own solution as an answer and accept it instead of my answer. Happy to see you have resolved it partly from what I've posted. Recursive calls are rather tricky to get right, I can generally only get them resolved by iteratively testing and adjusting the test.